# Class not found en consola en php

Tags: php, mongodb

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intento ejecutar un archivo php desde consola, estoy usando mongodb y al ejecutarlo desde consola me da este error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found in /var/www/html/PHP/sockets/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/PHP/sockets/server.php(35): MongoDB\Client->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/PHP/sockets/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 130

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found in /var/www/html/PHP/sockets/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/PHP/sockets/server.php(35): MongoDB\Client->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/PHP/sockets/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 130
```

Pero si lo ejecuto desde una página ya no da error, lo único que hago que creo que es la base del error es esto:

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
```

¿Alguien me puede decir cómo lo puedo arreglar? Desde ya gracias :).

### Edit

Hice este edit debido a que leyendo la respuesta pensé que el problema era que php no tiene la extensión mongodb y que la consola estaba usando la versión de php en la que no tengo el `extension=mongodb.so`, por lo que como tengo la versión 7 y la 8 pensé que la consola usaba la versión 7, y aunque le añadí la extension a el .ini de php7 cuando hago el phpinfo no encuentra la extensión de mongodb, ¿cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: entiendo que estas utilizando vendors... los has instalado? has ejecutado un `composer install`?

Comment: @Jakala no lo  había hecho, lo ejecute (el `composer install`) y ahora que lo volví a intentar pasa exactamente el mismo error

Comment: El archivo `ini` usado en el CLI de PHP no es el mismo usado por la interfaz web. Para saber dónde está el archivo `php.ini` usado por el CLI, debes escribir en la consola: `php --ini`. Esto te mostrará la ubicación del archivo `ini` cargado por el CLI, por ejemplo: `Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini`. Ese archivo es el que debes editar. (Nota: primero debes instalar la extensión de MongoDB en el CLI usando `sudo pecl install mongodb`, ver [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/)). Saludos

Comment: También puedes verificar la configuración `ini` de `mongodb`. Tal vez debas copiar desde el directorio `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/conf.d/` el archivo llamado `20-mongodb.ini` (si existe), al directorio `/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/`. En este caso estoy asumiendo que utilizas PHP 8.0, pero lo mismo aplicaría para PHP 7.x. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿si ya tengo mongodb instalado ya solo agrego el `extension=mongodb.so` al .ini file no?

Comment: Es interesante que revises si tienes el archivo `20-mongodb.ini` en la ubicación mencionada, ya que de esta forma sólo al copiarlo estarías activando la misma configuración que tienes en web hacia el CLI. Dale una ojeada.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya funcionó como dijiste, no se si te gustaría aregarlo como respuesta. Saludos y gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi problema lo logré resolver tal como dijo Mauricio Contreras, lo que es editar el archivo `/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini` y ahí mismo añadir el `extension=mongodb.so` , depués de intentar eso al ejecutar el archivo desde consola ya no da error

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El CLI de PHP utiliza un archivo de inicio (`php.ini`) diferente al que usa la interfaz web ([FPM](https://www.php.net/manual/es/install.fpm.php)), por lo cual los módulos que se cargan por defecto en FPM no siempre serán los mismos que se cargan en el CLI.

Cuando se [instala](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/) la extensión de MongoDB para PHP, usualmente se activa la misma (si no ha sido activada) agregando la siguiente linea al archivo `php.ini`:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

Sin embargo, si queremos asegurarnos de que la extensión se ha activado tanto en el entorno web (FPM) como en el entorno CLI, debemos añadir dicha linea en ambos archivos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

(Se asume PHP 8.0, si se desea aplicar esta solución para una versión deiferente, sustituir el valor 8.0 por la versión deseada en las rutas usadas en esta respuesta, también se asume que el sistema operativo utilizado es Linux con *systemd*)

Para saber cuál es el archivo `ini` que utiliza el CLI de PHP y su ubicación, basta escribir en la consola lo siguiente:

```sh
php --ini
```

Este comando nos mostrará algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```sh
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d
...
```

Ahora bien, un primer impulso es editar el archivo `php.ini` y agregar directamente la linea en cuestión, sin embargo, una *mejor* forma de hacerlo es crear enlaces simbólicos a un archivo `ini` que conseguiremos por lo general en el directorio `/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini`. Este archivo es creado durante el proceso de instalación de la extensión de MongoDB para PHP, y su contenido es el siguiente:

```sh
extension=mongodb.so
```

Lo que se sugiere es crear enlaces simbólicos para cada uno de los SAPI que requieran el uso de esta extensión.

Por ejemplo, si deseo habilitar la extensión en FPM, debo crear el enlace simbólico usando el siguiente comando:

```sh
sudo ln -sv /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini /etc/php/8.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
```

Esto nos devolverá la siguiente salida:

```sh
'/etc/php/8.0/fpm/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini' -> '/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini'
```

Luego debemos reiniciar el servicio FPM:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart php8.0-fpm
```

Para agregar el enlace al CLI de PHP ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

```sh
sudo ln -sv /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
```

Lo cual nos devolverá la siguiente linea:

```sh
'/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini' -> '/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini'
```

Ahora, al ejecutar desde la consola el comando `php --ini` podremos visualizar las extensiones cargadas desde la carpeta `conf.d` del CLI:

```sh
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:
...
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
...
```

Por último, podemos reiniciar el servidor Apache para que los cambios realizados sobre FPM surtan efecto:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas por consola el entorno no es el mismo que por web. Por ejemplo, tienes que asegurarte de que en el entorno de ejecución el directorio actual sea el de tu archivo PHP.

Puede servirte esta instrucción al inicio de tu script:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

El directorio actual es algo importante, pero no lo único. Atendiendo mejor a tu error, indica que **falta en PHP la extensión MongoDB**. Ésta no se echa en falta cuando ejecutas por web, eso quiere decir que no es el mismo PHP, o al menos no la misma configuración de PHP. Haz un script con phpinfo() y ejecútalo por consola y por web, y compara las salidas. En la de web seguramente veas información relativa a MongoDB, mientras que el la de consola no. Atiende a qué ejecuta PHP y qué .ini se carga.

Por consola estás ejecutando PHP directamente y estará cargando un archivo .ini de configuración, por web PHP se estará ejecutando bajo cgi, fastcgi, fpm,... y cargando una configuración distinta. Busca MongoDB y PHP, hay mucho, encontrarás algo que sea adecuado para tu caso.

Comment: Intente de la forma en la que lo dijiste pero aún asi me sigue diciendo que la clase no se encuentra, por lo que me genera el mismo error

Comment: cierto, si hago un `phpinfo()` desde la web si puedo ver la extensión mongodb activada, pero en la consola solo está mysql, ¿cómo puedo arreglar esto y que lo causa?

Comment: José Carlos PHP, ví la actualización de tu respuesta,  perdón por la pregunta pero ¿cómo puedo ver el php.ini que esta usando la consola?

Comment: En la información que saca phpinfo() puedes ver `Loaded configuration file`, que es el que más te interesa, y `Addtional ini files parsed`.